# How does standalone form control in ModelOptions affect form values

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validation

```
       <div id="resort-data" 
            ngModelGroup="resortData" 
            #resortData="ngModelGroup">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="text">Kod resortowy I:</div>
                <div class="data">
                    <underline-input id="resI" 
                       #resI="ngModel" 
                       [(ngModel)]="this.company.i_kod" 
                       name="resI" placeholder="Kod resortowy I" 
                       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                    </underline-input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If I use  `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` input and

`{{f.value | json}}`

is displayed that resortData is empty object if i remove   `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` that `"resortData": { "resI": "valueFromInput" } }` form is working and validation also working fine
why this is happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `standalone:true` option means that `ngModel` directive should not register the `formControl` it creates within the wrapping `formGroup`. Here is the relevant sources from the `ngModel` directive:

```
export class NgModel extends NgControl implements OnChanges,
      ...
      private _setUpControl(): void {
        this._setUpdateStrategy();
        this._isStandalone() ? this._setUpStandalone() :
                               this.formDirective.addControl(this); <--- is not called
        this._registered = true;
      }
```

Hence if you try to output all form controls here:

```
{{f.value | json}}
```

the form doesn't contain the control you pass as standalone.